Why does my dog hold his poo and drink his urine even though we let him out when he asks
We have a rescue who has been with us for 4 months. I'm home all day so when he asks to go out, I respond quickly. The problem came with him so to speak and I thought he would have relaxed enough by now to at least reduce the behaviour somewhat. He's still holding his poo and pee and I've noticed instead of asking to go out he drinks his own pee and will try and stop his poo from coming out.  When I let him out I have to stand with him while he does his business otherwise he won't go.  Is this a trauma issue and if so how can I correct it please.

Have you tried actually praising him for doing his business? Or is it just something that happens and then you go back inside without commenting on it?

Elmy, yes he does get praise when he goes to do his business.
